# Steps in taking the derivative and evaluating at 0 for a likelihood

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am working in branching process theory and developing a likelihood equation based on the negative binomial distribution. I came across a formula that take a derivative and evaluates it at 0, but I am unable to understand how they arrive at the final formula. The formulas provided are:

$$L(R,k\mid z,i)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z+1)}\frac{d^z}{ds^z} \left.\left(1+\frac{R}{k}(1-s)\right)^{-ki}\right|_{s=0}$$

Thus,

$$L(R,k\mid z,i)=\frac{\Gamma(z+ki)}{\Gamma(z+1)\Gamma(ki)}\left(\frac{k}{R+k}\right)^{ki} \left(\frac{R}{R+k}\right)^z$$

I have tried several pen-and-paper attempts at taking the derivative and evaluating at $s=0$, but have not arrived at their conclusion. Any assistance in the intermediate steps between these two equations would be would be much appreciated.

I have never posted on this forum, so if more information is needed, please let me know and I will edit.

Comment: If you are going to try a few values of $z$ (such as 1, 2, 3), then rewriting $1/(1+{R\over k}(1-s))$ as $k\over {k+R(1−s)}$ is helpful to get the result into the form of the second equation.